# The language expression property '0' can't be evaluated, property name must be a string - ARM Template error while adding Key Vault access policy

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-keyvault, azure-rm-template

I've been working on an issue and seem to be stuck, so asking on so in case anyone can help.

To describe the issue, I've got an existing Azure Key Vault setup, and wish to add a number of access policies to this resource group. It needs to be conditional as if the function name is "false" then that function should not be added to key vault access policy.

variable section:

```
 "variables": {
    "functionAccess": {
      "value": [
        {
          "name": "[parameters('Function_1')]"
        },
        {
          "name": "[parameters('Function_2')]"
        },
        {
          "name": "[parameters('Function_3')]"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

My Template :

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2016-10-01",
  "condition": "[not(equals(variables('functionAccess')[CopyIndex()].name, 'false'))]",
  "copy": {
    "batchSize": 1,
    "count": "[length(variables('functionAccess'))]",
    "mode": "Serial",
    "name": "accessPolicies"
  },
  "name": "[concat(parameters('KeyVault_Name'), '/add')]",
  "properties": {
    "accessPolicies": [
      {
        "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
        "objectId": "[if(not(equals(variables('functionAccess')[CopyIndex()].name, 'false')), reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('functionAccess')[CopyIndex()].name), '2016-08-01', 'Full').identity.principalId, json('null'))]",
        "permissions": {
          "keys": [
            "get",
            "list"
          ],
          "secrets": [
            "get",
            "list"
          ],
          "certificates": [
            "get",
            "list"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies"
}
```

When I deploy my ARM template for the azure key vault I got this error message:

> The language expression property '0' can't be evaluated, property name must be a string.

also tried below, but same error:

```
{
  "apiVersion": "2018-02-14",
  "name": "[concat(parameters('KeyVault_Name'), '/add')]",
  "properties": {
    "copy": [
      {
        "batchSize": 1,
        "count": "[length(variables('functionAccess'))]",
        "mode": "serial",
        "name": "accessPolicies",
        "input": {
          "condition": "[not(equals(variables('functionAccess')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].name, 'false'))]",
          "tenantId": "[subscription().tenantId]",
          "objectId": "[if(not(equals(variables('functionAccess')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].name, 'false')), reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', variables('functionAccess')[copyIndex('accessPolicies')].name), '2016-08-01', 'Full').identity.principalId, json('null'))]",
          "permissions": {
            "keys": [
              "get",
              "list"
            ],
            "secrets": [
              "get",
              "list"
            ],
            "certificates": [
              "get",
              "list"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "type": "Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults/accessPolicies"
}
```

Comment: Do you still need help with this? I have a similar case where I have a conditional access policy but I apply it during the create/update of the Key Vault resource `Microsoft.KeyVault/vaults` instead of during an `add` as you have here. The reason I didn't use `add` was because all my access policies got wiped out momentarily when redeploying the Key Vault ARM.

Comment: @Stringfellow in my case my Key vaults are created by a separate template that will be executed as part of the initial setup. I have to add these policies at a later stage. If you can share your template, can take a look if that would share any light. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options for dealing with filtering an array for `copy` operation. I deploy my ARM templates from PowerShell scripts and use PowerShell to setup parameter values. When I need special logic handle different inputs for different environments, I let PowerShell handle it.

If you must handle the filtering in ARM and you have the option to input a CSV list of functions, then perhaps the following will work. You can then use the `functionAccessArray` to iterate over in the `copy` operation.

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {

  },
  "variables": {
    "functionAccessCsv": "Function-0,Function-1,false,Function-4,false,Function-6,Function-7",
    "functionAccessFiltered": "[replace(replace(variables('functionAccessCsv'), 'false', ''), ',,', ',')]",
    "functionAccessArray": "[split(variables('functionAccessFiltered'), ',')]"
  },
  "resources": [
  ],
  "outputs": {
    "functionAccessCsvFiltered": {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "[variables('functionAccessFiltered')]"
    },
    "functionAccessArray": {
      "type": "array",
      "value": "[variables('functionAccessArray')]"
    }
  }
}
```

The result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Stringfellow. But I would like to do that in one ARM template if possible.

Comment: Thanks, @Stringfellow, this is the only solution on these circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue. By using an array parameter with a default value instead of a variable, I got it to work.

```
"parameters": {
    "functionAccess": {
      "type": "array",
      "defaultValue": [
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3"
      ]
    }
  }
```